# Rename [tkmessagebox] → [tkinter-messagebox]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

When Python 3 was released in 2008, the `tkmessagebox` module was renamed to `tkinter.messagebox` (See *[Which tkinter modules were renamed in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673174/3357935)*)

**I would like to propose renaming the [tkmessagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkmessagebox) tag to match the new name.**

- [tkmessagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkmessagebox) (49) → [tkinter-messagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter-messagebox)

Edit: I would also like to propose renaming [ttk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ttk) for the same reason.

- [ttk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ttk) (571) → [tkinter-ttk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter-ttk)

Comment: It's a very reasonable-sounding suggestion, but I'm not sure "renaming" is the *best* option. Maybe make the Python 2 module a synonym of the Python 3 module? Or maybe even keep them separate, since Python 2 is going to be around for a while? Or maybe don't worry about it, since it the activity level is so low and there's only one follower?